# how do I encode a complete http url String correctly?

Tags: java, urlencode

I get a url string from a user and would like to transform it to a legal http url:

"**http://one.two/three?four five**" should turn into "**http://one.two/three?four%20five**"

however, URLEncoder does not help, as it encodes the entire string (including the legal "://").

help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With external library:

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.util.URIUtil;
String myUrl_1= "http://one.two/three?four five";
System.out.println(URIUtil.encodeQuery(myUrl_1));
```

And the output:

```
http://one.two/three?four%20five
```

Or

```
String webResourceURL = "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=<script>alert(1)</script> s";
System.out.println(URIUtil.encodeQuery(webResourceURL));
```

And the output:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%3Cscript%3Ealert(1)%3C/script%3E%20s
```

And the Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the `URL` class. For example:

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
String encodedQueryString = URLEncoder.encode(url.getQuery());
String encodedUrl = urlString.replace(url.getQuery(), encodedQueryString);
```

The third line might be different - for example constructing a new `URL` from all its parts.

Comment: Should we encode query parameter separators like `?` and `=`?