# How do I save a large file from a URL to the local

Tags: java

I have tried this below code which is working fine with the small size files.

```
URL url = new URL(downloadLink);
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
fos.close();
rbc.close();
```

If the file is a large file, it is giving an error like :

```
java.io.IOException:Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/79q8i6f9zqx7y2w/Paragliding in Himalayas.avi
```

Can anyone help me.

Comment: How large is "large", and does the HTTP response contain any other useful information other than the 400 code?

Comment: 200MB file size. java.io.IOException:Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:XXXXXX only this message was throwing

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java

Comment: @SudhirOjhaI have tried all ways mentioned in that post. no luck

Comment: Look at here also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045003/how-to-download-large-sized-files-size-50mb-in-java

Comment: One interesting observation here is that the `400` status code would be sent before you start actually reading the full bytes of the file, indicating that the server is unhappy about some part of the request (e.g. headers that sent) hence a client error. Are you able to increase the log level of your application to show the full request headers being sent?

Comment: The URL you're trying to download is invalid.  URLs can't contain spaces.  You need to URL encode it: `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/79q8i6f9zqx7y2w/Paragliding%20in%20Himalayas.avi`
Important note, you'll need to URL encode everything after the machine name, otherwise, it'll encode the protocol too.

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292579/how-do-i-encode-a-complete-http-url-string-correctly, FWIW, I used your existing code, and got it to work fine by manually passing a hand-coded URL.

Comment: @JasonArmstrong, thanks for your suggestion, it's working fine. If you post your suggestion as an answer I will accept it and do upvote for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you're trying to download is invalid. URLs can't contain spaces. You need to URL encode it:

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/79q8i6f9zqx7y2w/Paragliding%20in%20Himalayas.avi
```

Have a look at: [how do I encode a complete http url String correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292579/how-do-i-encode-a-complete-http-url-string-correctly), for an approach to encoding the URL.  Unfortunately, just using `URLEncoder.encode()` won't cut it, since it encodes slashes, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can hand this task over to Os itself by using DownloadManager

```
 private fun startDownload(url: String) {
    val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner()
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/")))
    val dm = activity!!.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    dm.enqueue(request)
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like Java to me.